# For $2 \leq r\leq n$. to what does $^nC_r + 2\times^nC_{r-1} + ^nC_{r-2}$ is equal to?

Tags: combinations

Needed help for the following question in combination?

For $2 \leq r\leq n$. To what does$^nC_r + 2\times^nC_{r-1} + ^nC_{r-2}$ is equal to ?

Thank's

Akash

Comment: I really didn't tried to solve it cause I am not getting what the question asking to do if you can tell that also then it would also help

Comment: what all do you know about $^nC_r$???

Comment: well I know enough just having problem with the language of the ques

Comment: well, if you know enough, it would not be difficult for you to see at least what is the question.... Do not try to be rude... Ask help and please don't place orders..

Comment: haha no I am not being rude but apologies if it sounded like that and I am not placing order's just came here for help in place I thought I could get one

Comment: $\TeX$tip: one usually writes `\binom{n}{k}` to get $\binom{n}{k}$, which is a much more readable notation!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez : Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual Question is to calculate what does $\binom{n}{r}+2\binom{n}{r-1}+\binom{n}{r-2}$ equal to???

With out assuming much,

we have $\binom{n}{r}+\binom{n}{r-1}=\frac{n!}{(n-r)! r!}+\frac{n!}{(n-(r-1))! (r-1)!}$

$\frac{n!}{(n-r)! r!}+\frac{n!}{(n-(r-1))! (r-1)!}=\frac{n!}{(n-r)! r!}+\frac{n!}
{(n-r+1))! (r-1)!}$

$\frac{n!}{(n-r)! r!}+\frac{n!}
{(n-r+1))! (r-1)!}=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!(r-1)!}(\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{n-r+1})$

$\frac{n!}{(n-r)!(r-1)!}(\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{n-r+1})=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!(r-1)!}(\frac{n-r+1+r}{r.(n-r+1)})$

$\frac{n!}{(n-r)!(r-1)!}(\frac{n-r+1+r}{r.(n-r+1)})=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!(r-1)!}(\frac{n+1}{r.(n-r+1)})$

$\frac{n!}{(n-r)!(r-1)!}(\frac{n+1}{r.(n-r+1)})=\frac{(n+1)n!}{(n-r+1)(n-r)!.r(r-1)!}$

$\frac{(n+1)n!}{(n-r+1)(n-r)!.r(r-1)!}=\frac{(n+1)!}{(n-r+1)!r!}=\frac{(n+1)!}{((n+1)-r)!.r!}=\binom{n+1}{r}$

Thus, we conclude that $\binom{n}{r}+\binom{n}{r-1}=\binom{n+1}{r}$

with similar observation, (replacing $r$ by $r-1$) we have $\binom{n}{r-1}+\binom{n}{r-2}=\binom{n+1}{r-1}$

and so $\binom{n}{r}+2\binom{n}{r-1}+\binom{n}{r-2}=\binom{n}{r}+\binom{n}{r-1}+\binom{n}{r-1}+\binom{n}{r-2}$

As we have already seen that $\binom{n}{r}+\binom{n}{r-1}=\binom{n+1}{r}$ and $\binom{n}{r-1}+\binom{n}{r-2}=\binom{n+1}{r-1}$

we have $\binom{n}{r}+2\binom{n}{r-1}+\binom{n}{r-2}=\binom{n}{r}+\binom{n}{r-1}+\binom{n}{r-1}+\binom{n}{r-2}=\binom{n+1}{r}+\binom{n+1}{r-1}=\binom{n+2}{r}$

So, we have $\binom{n}{r}+2\binom{n}{r-1}+\binom{n}{r-2}=\binom{n+2}{r}$

Comment: ok question is solved but I am still confused what was the use of the condition $2\leq r \leq n$

Comment: please convince yourself that one can not use $r-2$ in binomial coefficient if $r=1$ or $r=0$.... and you know why $r\leq n$ ;)